# Equivalent of an "except" command in R when subsetting a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataset like that :

| ID | Amount | MemberCard |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 345890 | 251000 | NO |
| 341862 | 400238 | YES |
| 345791 | 678921 | YES |
| 341750 | 87023 | NO |
| 345716 | 12987 | YES |

I need to delete all the observations with an amount > 250000, but i have to keep the IDs 341862 & 345791. So i was wondering if a kind of "except" command exists in R when subsetting, instead of creating a data frame with these 2 observations only and rbind after.

Answer (score 1):

Select a row if `ID` is one of  `c(341862, 345791)` OR if `Amount` is less than equal to 25000.

We can use `subset` in base R -

```
res <- subset(df, ID %in% c(341862, 345791) | Amount <= 25000)
res

#      ID Amount MemberCard
#1 341862 400238        YES
#2 345791 678921        YES
#3 345716  12987        YES
```

Or with `dplyr::filter` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter(ID %in% c(341862, 345791) | Amount <= 25000)
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to have empty values for observations with `Amount > 250000`, you can use `replace()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_new <- df %>% 
  mutate(Amount = replace(Amount, Amount >250000, NA))
```

If you want the results to be applied to both columns, you can just add it to `mutate()`:

```
df_new <- df %>% 
  mutate(Amount = replace(Amount, Amount > 250000, NA),
         MemberCard = replace(Amount, Amount > 250000, NA))
```

This will preserve the ID, but removes all other values if the condition is met. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

We may also use

```
subset(df, ID == 341862| ID == 345791|Amount <= 25000)
```